# How to add icons to Dojo grid header?

Tags: dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

How can i add icon to dojo grid header. I tried setting the headerClasses with appropriate css class but dint work.

sample css class i used

```
.sample{
background : url ('______') no-repeat right top;
}
```

this never worked for me.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

basically you needed to add ".tundra" in front of .sample because the .tundra stylesheet is at the top of the hierarchy.

I found the solution wich may help you here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2456933/1238394

Comment: @Vikram If the answer is helpful you need to accept it. Click on checkmark under upvote/downwote counter of the answer. This will mark question as closed and provide you with small reputation bonus.

Comment: @Vikram If the answer is helpful pleace accept it as Artemix said.